# postgresql sql query syntax error at or near "convert_from" in python

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, hash, bytea

i think this is easy question, how to write sql query in python?

```
### python3 code
# ok 
row = await conn.fetchrow(
    'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $1', user_email)

# NOT ok
user_pw = await conn.fetch(                                                          
    'convert_from($1, $2)', row[2], 'UTF8')
```

> asyncpg.exceptions.PostgresSyntaxError: syntax error at or near
>   "convert_from"

Comment: Well `convert_from()` is a function that needs a `SELECT`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ok i will check and test and report the result tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had fixed my bug with following code:

```
tmp_pw = await conn.fetch(
    'SELECT * FROM convert_from($1, $2)', row[2], 'UTF8')

# because, tmp_pw is  
#[<Record convert_from='$2a$12$PsXD/oaDXwC1Ffup842I/emQ3Bz26AWjQNsLBQipQ4gvRIFhUQAXb2'>]
# any suggestion is welcome.
user_pw = str(tmp_pw).strip('[]').strip('<>').split('=')[1].strip('\'')

# another method to get pw from Record (not tested):
# tmp_iter = iter(tmp_pw)
# user_pw = next(tmp_iter)
```